# REACT - I'm trying to store an image from a file type input, but it doesn't store the path in the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, jsx

I'm trying to store an image from a file type input, but it doesn't store the path in the database, follow the code below along with the error I get. I am storing the images in a folder in the code but it sends the path to the database, but the image address is not arriving in the database

Register.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Register = () => {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const [err, setError] = useState(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const baseURL = "http://localhost:8800/api";

  const upload = async () => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", file);
      const res = await axios.post(`${baseURL}/upload`, formData, {withCredentials: true});
      return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputs((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const imgUrl = await upload();
    try {
      await axios.post(`${baseURL}/auth/register`, inputs, imgUrl, { withCredentials: true });
      navigate("/login");
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.response.data);
    };
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <h1>Create Account</h1>
      <form>
        <input className="custom-file-upload" type="file" id="file" onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])} />
        <input required type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input required type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input required type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Register</button>
        {err && <p>{err}</p>}
        <span>
          Do you have an account?
          <Link className="login" to="/login">Login</Link>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

index.js

```
import express, { json } from "express";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import multer from "multer";
import "dotenv/config.js";

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true
}), json());
app.use(cookieParser());

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '../client/public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), function (req, res) {
  const file = req.file;
  res.status(200).json(file.filename);
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8800, () => {
  console.log("=============")
  console.log("Connected!");
  console.log("=============")
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bkpn.png)

I'm receiving this error.

Comment: You cant access localhost like this. You need to create an https server. Generate SSL certs and give the path in your server.

Comment: I was using a proxy, however it wasn't working, using this method it works, but of course, when I upload the application, I will change the way this is done, but for development tests, I will keep it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is likely occurring because you're trying to pass imgUrl as a separate parameter in your request, but Axios doesn't expect it to be a separate parameter. Instead, you should include imgUrl in the request body along with the other inputs. Here's how you should modify your handleSubmit function to fix the issue:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const imgUrl = await upload();
  try {
    await axios.post(`${baseURL}/auth/register`, { ...inputs, imgUrl }, { withCredentials: true });
    navigate("/login");
  } catch (err) {
    setError(err.response.data);
  }
};
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much friend, this solved it!